Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive in `gcd` function
For learning purposes, I am defining gcd' function in terms of repeated subtraction:
gcd' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
gcd' x y 
    | x == y = x
    | x < y = gcd' x (y - x)
    | y < x = gcd' (x - y) y

(Prelude's gcd function)
The problem is GHC complains about it:

Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive.
In an equation for ‘gcd'’:


Patterns of type ‘Integer’, ‘Integer’ not matched: _ _

I've seen a mathematical law concerning numbers which said:

For all numbers  and , it is true that either  is less than , or  is less than , or  equals .

In that sense, those three guards cover all possible scenarios. Why is GHC concerned about this definition ?

Does this answer your question? Why do non-exhaustive guards cause irrefutable pattern match to fail?


Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive. In an equation for ‘gcd'’:

The problem is that Haskell is not that clever to know that for two items x and y, it always holds that x < y, x > y or x == y, and in fact it does not even hold. Indeed, for a NaN, it does not hold:
ghci> nan = 0/0
ghci> nan
NaN
ghci> nan == nan
False
ghci> nan > nan
False
ghci> nan < nan
False

It is better to work with a condition that is always true: otherwise, which is an alias for True:
gcd' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
gcd' x y 
    | x == y = x
    | x < y = gcd' x (y - x)
    | otherwise = gcd' (x - y) y
Note that a faster implementation of gcd' is:
gcd' :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
gcd' a b
  | b == 0 = a
  | otherwise = gcd' b (a `mod` b)

Thank you so much as always ! I perfectly understood. Do you know the type of NaN ?

@F.Zer: Float or Double. It is indeed not applicable for Integers. The point is that it is a bit unreliable to assume that for every two items of the same type and instance of Ord, it holds that x == y, x < y, or x > y.

Thank you ! I've just noticed that I have a bug in my definition of gcd'. If one of the arguments (but not both) are zero, the function does not terminate ? Do you know how can I solve it ?

Occurs to me that I could add another condition x == 0 || y == 0, but perhaps there is a standard solution to that problem

@F.Zer: I think it is the algorithm itself that does not take 0 into account. If you use Euclid's method (see edit) this works, it is a faster but probably also "simpler" algorithm.

Thank you, I see your edit. In Hutton's book, euclid is I think the version which uses repeated subtraction.

I always thought that the euclidean method used repeated subtraction instead of mod; however, your solution seems neater.

I see your last version gives different results than Prelude's version: gcd 8 (-2) == 2 and gcd' 8 (-2) == -2

Though, I think that would be incorrect. The greatest number that divides both 8 and (-2) evenly is 2 not -2. Does that make sense ?

@F.Zer: I think the sign does not really matter? So probably we can use abs (gcd' x y), which normally should guarantee the greatest common divider.

As Willem explained, this is because GHC doesn't know that < / > / == are an exhaustive collection of possibilities. In fact it never knows that for any boolean-valued checks.
Haskell does however have an alternative where GHC is able to deduce exhaustiveness: pattern matching on sum types. And that can also be used for making decisions based on ordering. Your algorithm would look thus:
gcd' x y = case compare x y of
   EQ -> x
   LT -> gcd' x (y - x)
   GT -> gcd' (x - y) y

I'd say this is actually better than the version with otherwise.

This is amazing ! Thank you so much for posting this answer.
